# How to open the specified window.location page in this html document? what do i need to change in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I made a spin to win website but with each win , same page is being opened each and every time.

Only the first page mentioned in the code i.e, prize_22.html is only being opened every time.

I would like to open page with their respective id's.

It must open after a delay of 5 seconds.

Here is the javascript below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('.easywheel').easyWheel({
    items: [
        {  //Here are some details
            id      : 'a',
            name    : 'PayTM cash',
            message : 'You won PayTM cash of rupees 5000',
            color   : '#3498db',
            win     : true
        },{
            id      : 'b',
            name    : 'Macbook Pro',
            message : ' You won Macbook Pro 13" with touchbar',
            color   : '#ffc107',
            win     : true
        },{
            id      : 'c',
            name    : 'Chocolate box',
            message : 'You got one Ferrero Rpcher chocolate box',
            color   : '#f44336',
            win     : true
        },{
            id      : 'd',
            name    : 'Lose',
            message : 'You Lose :(',
            color   : '#3498db',
            win     : false
        },{
            id      : 'e',
            name    : 'Trip to Dubai',
            message : 'You won a trip to Dubai',
            color   : '#ffc107',
            win     : true
        },{
            id      : 'f',
            name    : 'iPhone 11 Pro',
            message : 'You get iPhone 11 Pro 256 gb',
            color   : '#f44336',
            win     : true
        }
    ],
    random: true,
    button : '.spin-to-win',
    onStart: function(results, spinCount, now) {
        $('.spinner-message').css('color','#90A4AE');
        $('.spinner-message').html('Spinning...');
    },
    onComplete : function(results,count,now){

        $('.spinner-message').css('color',results.color).html(results.message);
        console.log(results,count,now);
        if (id='g'){
            window.location="prize_22.html"
        }
        else if (id='b'){
            window.location="prize_01.html"
        }
        else if (id='c'){
            window.location="prize_44.html"
        }
        else if (id='d'){
            window.location="prize_33.html"
        }
        else if (id='e'){
            window.location="prize_555.html"
        }
        else{
            window.location="prize_666.html"
        }
    }//open the above mentioned page
});
```

Comment: Please note that ***if (id='b')*** is not ***if (id=='b')***

Comment: used '==' and '===' both but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` instead of singl `=` here

```
    if (id == 'g'){
        window.location="prize_22.html"
    }
    else if (id == 'b'){
        window.location="prize_01.html"
    }
    else if (id == 'c'){
        window.location="prize_44.html"
    }
    else if (id == 'd'){
        window.location="prize_33.html"
    }
    else if (id == 'e'){
        window.location="prize_555.html"
    }
    else{
        window.location="prize_666.html"
    }
```

It'll work hopefully

Comment: Change also `if (id =='g')` (and others) to `if (results.id =='g')`

Comment: Worked with (results.id =='g')

Answer (score -2):

please use `===` instead of `=`.
In the future try to use `===` is better than `==`.

Comment: This should really be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: While I can see how this "could" be the issue, as understanding the correct syntax is important, your answer as stated doesn't really explain much and should belong to a comment instead. Please review your answer to better explain what the mistake was, why it is a mistake and how the code should be changed to address the issue. Once this is done, I'll remove my downvote.